# Handle re-calling a function inside useEffect when "Back Button" clicked from a user in React

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to not call `loadUserPosts()` function again if the user clicks the 'back button' on his browser.
I think this is because of the `isLogged` useState because is changing when clicking the back button.

The `loadUserPosts` function is inside an `useEffect` only if the user is logged, so I have this:

In Posts.js component I have this:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { AuthUseContext } from  '../context/AuthContext';
import Axios from 'axios';

function Posts() {
    const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);
    const { isLogged, setIsLogged, userData, setUserData } = AuthUseContext();

    useEffect(() => {
        if(isLogged) {
            loadUserPosts();
        }
    }, [isLogged]);

    // my API request to load all user posts
    function loadUserPosts()
    {
        Axios.post('/posts/load', {
            user: userData.id
        }).then((response) => {
            if(response.data.status === "success")
            {
                setPosts(response.data.posts);
            }
        }).catch((error) => {
            console.log("Something went wrong.. We are investigating.");
        })
    }

    return (
        <>
            {posts.map((p) => {
                <div className="post" key={p.id}>
                    <div className="post-user">
                        {p.username}
                    </div>
                    <div className="post-text">
                        {p.message}
                    </div>
                </div>
            })}
        </>
    )
}

export default Posts
```

If I remove the dependecies `[isLogged]` the isLogged will be `false` because the result from API Request in App.js has not been sent yet.

In app.js I have an API request to backend to check if the user is logged in or not (using NodeJs/Express as backend with cookie-session as middleware).

```
import { useEffect } from 'react'
import { Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom'

import './css/style.css'

import Sidebar from './pages/Sidebar'
import Posts from './pages/Posts'

import { AuthUseContext } from  './context/AuthContext';

import Axios from 'axios'

function App() {
    const { isLogged, setIsLogged, userData, setUserData } = AuthUseContext();

    useEffect(() => {
        Axios.post('/checkuser', {
            userStatus: isLogged,
            userData: userData
        }).then((response) => {
            setIsLogged(response.data.status); // true / false
            setUserData(response.data.userdata); // { id: ..., name: ..., ...etc...}
        }).catch(function (error) {
            console.log("Something went wrong.. We are investigating.");
        });
        // eslint-disable-next-line
    }, [isLogged])

    return (
        <>
            <Sidebar />
            <div className="content">
                <Routes>
                    <Route path="/" element={<Posts />} />
                    <Route path="*" element={ <h1>Not found (404)</h1> } />
                </Routes>
            </div>
        </>
    );
    
}

export default App;
```

Can someone help me or how should I structure my components?

Answer (score 0):

Use react query it handle network caching so it will not make a request again

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using useEffect and in that you are calling the API. So, it is not possible to stop the calling of API.
As per your code, it is going to be called for the very first time once you visit the screen.

For reference, kindly check this post regarding the useEffect https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html